# JSP: Get MIME Type on File Upload

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload, mime-types

I'm doing a file upload, and I want to get the Mime type from the uploaded file.

I was trying to use the **request.getContentType()**, but when I call:

```
String contentType = req.getContentType();
```

It will return:

> multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------310662768914663

How can I get the correct value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It sounds like as if you're homegrowing a `multipart/form-data` parser. I wouldn't recommend to do that. Rather use a decent one like [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload). For uploaded files, it offers a [`FileItem#getContentType()`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getContentType%28%29) to extract the client-specified content type, if any.

```
String contentType = item.getContentType();
```

If it returns `null` (just because the client didn't specify it), then you can take benefit of [`ServletContext#getMimeType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getMimeType%28java.lang.String%29) based on the file name.

```
String filename = FilenameUtils.getName(item.getName());
String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(filename);
```

This will be resolved based on `<mime-mapping>` entries in servletcontainer's default `web.xml` (in case of for example Tomcat, it's present in `/conf/web.xml`) and also on the `web.xml` of your webapp, if any, which can expand/override the servletcontainer's default mappings.

You however need to keep in mind that the value of the multipart content type is fully controlled by the client and also that the client-provided file extension does not necessarily need to represent the *actual* file content. For instance, the client could just edit the file extension. Be careful when using this information in business logic.

#### Related:

- [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)
- [How to check whether an uploaded file is an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169713/how-to-check-a-uploaded-file-whether-it-is-a-image-or-other-file)

Comment: Helped me. My one was specifying `'application/octet-stream'` for `MultipartFile attachmentFile = multipartRequest.getFile("filename") `
And only `getServletContext().getMimeType(filename)` gave me real content type.

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
public String ServletContext.getMimeType(String file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MimetypesFileTypeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html)

```
String contentType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(fileName)); // gets mime type
```

However, you would encounter the overhead of editing the mime.types file, if the file type is not already listed. (Sorry, I take that back, as you could add instances to the map programmatically and that would be the first place that it checks)