# finding file extension by java code

Tags: java, file-upload, file-extension

Suppose users can upload files, I want to find the extension of the uploaded file.
Even if the user has renamed the extension of the file, I want to find the real extension of that file by it's header or bytecode..etc.

Please help me with a solution.

**Note:** Not just the extension by substring() or getContentType() but the real file extension, 
say for example(in windows), its a .doc file and user renames it to .jpg and uploads it.
Its possible in php, but I don't know how to do that in java! but it can be done.
Thank you.

Comment: duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096862/jsp-get-mime-type-on-file-upload

Comment: i mentioned not getContentType()! this is different

Comment: how do you know what the "real" extension is without understanding the content type?

Comment: requirement is not content type, it never is. Suppose the user edits the extension from .jpg to .gif, content type will return image/gif or image/jpg ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apache Commons: FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) is a good place to start.  further, you could look at the link i referenced:  [JSP: Get MIME Type on File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096862/jsp-get-mime-type-on-file-upload) for hints on how to do this.

As the user states in their question, the thought is if i rename a *.png* to a *.jpg* this will fool the getContentType() into thinking it's now a *.jpg* file.  A quick search on google provided the following answer result:  [Get the mime type from a file](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html) that lists 3 very good options:

1. [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/)

   > The Apache Tika™ toolkit detects and extracts metadata and structured text content from various documents using existing parser libraries
2. [JMimeMagic](https://github.com/arimus/jmimemagic)

   > jMimeMagic is a Java library for determining the MIME type of files or streams
3. A java library that claims to help you with this, is:  [mime-util](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/)

   > Enable Java programs to detect MIME types based on file extensions, magic data and content sniffing. Supports detection from java.io.File, java.io.InputStream, java.net.URL and byte arrays.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search brought this post up: http://fredeaker.blogspot.com/2006/12/file-type-mime-detection.html

The post lists several "magic" libraries that can detect the file type based on its contents.