# Get the file extension from the Content type

Tags: java, servlets, content-type

I get the content type from the header, I need to get the extension of this content type.

eg: content type is `application/java-archive` then I want a string output as `jar`.

Comment: There is no mapping from content type to file extension. E.g. the content type `image/jpeg` may be mapped to either `.jpg` or `.jpeg`. Also how do you want to map `application/octet-stream` which is used for any binary file?

Comment: It would be better to generate the file extension where the the content type is generated. Otherwise you can construct a map content-type -> extension of your preference. As mentioned, there is not exact mapping between mime types and file extensions.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? If you can add more context that would be helpful for answerers. Thanks.

Comment: I need to restrict some types of file as a attachment

Comment: Ok , got your point . Is there a way to get the extension directly from the header ?

Comment: @Mizan limit the files to the content type not to any extension.

Comment: @Mizan At the moment I don't know but there could be a header with the file name.

Comment: I can get the file name from the params :) so i will check the file name now .However checking the content type is much better i believe. if i check conten type then the user cant upload a .bat file just by changing the file extension.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169713/how-to-check-a-uploaded-file-whether-it-is-a-image-or-other-file/4169776#4169776