# Check given file is Simple Text File using Java

Tags: java

I need to import large text files into database.
Structure of that text file is predefine using several separator and all.
I just need to check if given file is text file or not (regardless of extension).

How is it possible using Java?

Comment: Do you just need to confirm it's a text file or do you need to know that it conforms to your expected structure?

Comment: Actually I concern both for my code but here I just need help for text file check.

Comment: In a WebApp or from a Java app running on client ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios I didn't understood what you want to ask. but I am working on web application. through browser file will be uploaded to server and import to database on server. So I need to validate given file.

Comment: Ok, then through HTTP. It is actually easier than in a standalone application, and most frameworks have their own implementations to help you on this. Are you using a specific framework, like Struts2 for example ?

Comment: No I am using simple jsp/servlets

Comment: Impossible in general. You have to make assumptions about the encoding,  or the set of possible encodings.

Comment: Impossible without using any of the N methods listed (nor any of the methods un-listed)... :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- **In a standalone Java application**

  - Java 1.6 or lower (`java.io.File`)

    ```
    File file = new File("/myFolder/myFile");
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
    ```
  - Java 1.7 or higher (`java.nio.file.Path` - through installed [`FileTypeDetector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileTypeDetector.html) invoked with [`java.nio.file.Files.probeContentType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#probeContentType%28java.nio.file.Path%29)

    ```
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("myFolder", "myFile");
    String mimeType = Files.probeContentType(path);
    ```
- **In a framework agnostic web application**

  - Use a 3rd party library like [JMimeMagic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/) or [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) like described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4169776/1654265) answer:

    ```
    InputStream is = uploadedFile.getInputStream();
    String mimeType = Magic.getMagicMatch(is, false).getMimeType();
    ```
- **In a Struts2 web application**

  - through Struts2 [`FileUploadInterceptor.setAllowedTypes()`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/FileUploadInterceptor.html#setAllowedTypes%28java.lang.String%29)

    ```
    <!-- 
        Configured either 
            - globally to a package or 
            - locally to an Action
        in Struts.xml
    -->
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="allowedTypes">image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    ```

  More documentation on [FileUploadInterceptor](https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/file-upload-interceptor.html) and [FileUpload](https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/file-upload.html)
- **Client side in a web application**

  - with `HTML5`'s `accept` attribute of `<input type="file" />` (as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10503561/1654265) answer)

    ```
    <input type="file" accept="image/*,video/*">
    ```

---

I left out all the solutions based on the file extension (that often are not enough reliable) and some alternative 3rd party libraries and older solution.

Feel free to notice me what I may have forgotten, and I'll be happy to include it here.

Comment: Great solutions... Even for future reference for others. Thanks Andrea..

Answer (score 5):

I think the best you can manage is to check whether every byte in the file corresponds to a valid character in the charset you expect.

For example, if you believe this to be a UTF-8 encoded text file, you can try something like this to "validate" each byte:

```
try {  
  Charset.availableCharsets().get("UTF-8").newDecoder()
      .decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytesFromFile));  
  // was valid
} catch (CharacterCodingException e) {  
  // wasn't valid
}
```

Comment: Thanks... It looks good idea but for large files to check byte by byte is not a good idea. and one more question. Other then text file charsets are different?